# Implement Request Response pattern using Kafka + .Net Core + MassTransit

Tags: .net-core, apache-kafka, masstransit, request-response, confluent-kafka-dotnet

Can someone tell me how to implement request response pattern using kafka with .net core (2.1,2. or 3.1). I prefer to implement this pattern using MassTransit which is light weight message bus. I was not able to find reference implementation among their documentation. May be i missed it. Can someone,  share some standard reference implementation using MassTransit. If it can't be found, any samples (Implementation of Request Response pattern) implemented using Confluent Kafka is also great to see.

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is not designed for RPC, so doing request/response on Kafka would not be recommended. And is also why MassTransit doesn't support request/response using Kafka topics.

Comment: Okay Noted , If I need to convince some person not use kafka to implement request/response pattern how can i do that . I have few more questions to ask  based on your reply , 1 ) If kafka is not designed for request/response pattern then can you elaborate why ? 2 ) Don't we have any other standard approach to implement request/response pattern using kafka if I don't have a choice, Because this pattern is supported by spring boot/java out of the box with kafka.  3)  Can we use RMQ to implement request/response pattern along with MassTransit or confluent kafka ? appreciate your response , Thanks

Comment: You're leaning into the area of opinion, vs. what vendors want you to believe about their product's capabilities. I don't support request/response with Kafka, end of story. Use a broker for those messaging patterns.

Comment: Use a broker means to use RabbitMQ ?

Comment: Yes, RabbitMQ, Azure Service Bus, ActiveMQ, SQS are the brokers supported by MassTransit.